# preallocation and vector

Tags: c++, vector

In c++, for vector,
    why preallocation is so important even if vector alocates space dynamically

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, it's unlikely to be "so important" for 99% of cases.

It's basically an optimization.  Since vector doesn't have any idea how many elements you are going to add to it, it assumes a small default, and will have to grow if you try to add a new element and there is not enough space for a new element to be added.
The grow operation can be costly as it may require allocating an entirely new buffer, copying the current contents of the vector to the new buffer, and deallocating the old buffer. By preallocating enough space, if you know how many elements you are going to add, you can avoid unnecessary growth.

Like any performance optimization, you shouldn't worry about it unless it's a bottleneck. Moreover, if you have no idea how many elements you're going to add, let the vector decide. Don't assume your randomly chosen number is going to work better than the implementation default.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers already covered the theory, but I'd like to throw in also some numbers to get a feeling of what is happening.

Once I wrote a little test suite to compare `std::vector` `push_back`, `reserve`+`push_back`, sizing in constructor (which should be the same of `resize`) + `operator[]` and raw dynamic arrays; here are the results for 10000000 `int`s:

```
matteo@teoubuntu:~/cpp/vectorbenchmark2$ ./vectorbenchmark2 
Insert the number of elements: 10000000
Insert the number of iterations: 100
Minimum allocation for each benchmark 40000000 bytes.
Starting benchmark std::vector<int> (push_back/iterator, without reserve)... benchmark completed.
Results: 173.1 +/- 2.4 ms
Starting benchmark std::vector<int> (push_back/iterator, with reserve)... benchmark completed.
Results: 122.17 +/- 0.57 ms
Starting benchmark std::vector<int> (sized with constructor/operator[])... benchmark completed.
Results: 115.95 +/- 0.66 ms
Starting benchmark new int[]... benchmark completed.
Results: 121.33 +/- 0.84 ms
Starting benchmark malloc+memset... benchmark completed.
Results: 123.9 +/- 4.3 ms
Starting benchmark malloc... benchmark completed.
Results: 117.7 +/- 2.3 ms
Starting benchmark std::list<int>... benchmark completed.
Results: 552 +/- 35 ms
```

Each benchmark consists of allocation of the data structure, filling it with random numbers and re-reading everything in a `volatile` variable. The tests are performed as many times as specified in the second parameter asked (on this run I put 100); times are measured with `gettimeofday`. The displayed results are the mean and the standard deviation calculated on all the times of each category. The code for the whole thing is available [here](http://www.mitalia.net/uploads/Matteo/vectorbenchmark2.tar.gz).

What results can we draw from this data?

- the first obvious result is that the `push_back` without preallocation is the slowest method: in these conditions it's ~41% slower than the `push_back` *with* preallocation. So, if time is a critical factor and computing more or less how big will your `vector` need to be is not difficult, `reserve` may be really convenient. Obviously, if your allocation+fill in general takes ~10 ms even cutting it of 40% won't be really noticed; as usual, optimize where it makes sense (i.e. on bottlenecks).
- another interesting result is that initializing the size of the array (instead of doing a "transparent" preallocation with `reserve`) is even faster; I think that this is because we aren't calling `push_back` (that must update the `vector` "official size") in a tight loop; instead, `operator[]` does almost nothing more than a pointer sum and is easily inlined. Maybe using iterators (which in the case of `vector` are basically pointers) something more can be gained.
- interestingly, the only real contender with a ready-`resize`d `vector` is simple `malloc`, which offers no bells and whistles and isn't suitable for non-POD types (and still in this very test results in slightly worse performances). It's a great thing that `vector` can be *that* efficient while keeping its advantages (I'm talking to you, people who spread C-style `mallocs` around for supposed gains in performance!)
- `std::list` (put in for comparison) is the slowest of all them - but we already knew it `:)`

Obviously YMMV; first of all, these are the results on a particular architecture, with a particular compiler and its particular STL implementation (namely, g++ 4.4.5). Then, I think that using "complex" types (with constructors, copy constructors, etc) may reverse the positions of the `reserve`/`resize` methods (`resize` needs to construct all the objects in the `vector`, while I don't think `reserve` does). Some changes can also come from changing the primitive type used (`int` vs `long` vs `short` etc).

Moreover, between all the tests but the first and the last one the difference is quite little; it's surely significantly bigger than the standard deviation, but I think that even small changes in the standard library may change some of their relative results. Also, changing the number of elements should also have noticeable effects, since these times are sums of different big-O operations, so increasing or decreasing the number of elements can change the predominant addendum in the sum.

---

**Test conditions** (boring stuff)

AMD Phenom X4 955 (3.2 GHz x4), 4 GB RAM DDR3

Compiler:

```
matteo@teoubuntu:~/cpp/vectorbenchmark2$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

OS/Kernel:

```
matteo@teoubuntu:~/cpp/vectorbenchmark2$  uname -a
Linux teoubuntu 2.6.35-24-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 2 02:41:37 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Compilation options:

```
matteo@teoubuntu:~/cpp/vectorbenchmark2$ make
g++ -O3 -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic   -MMD -MF BenchmarkFunctors.o.d -c -o BenchmarkFunctors.o BenchmarkFunctors.cpp
g++ -O3 -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic   -MMD -MF main.o.d -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -O3 -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic   -MMD -MF Utils.o.d -c -o Utils.o Utils.cpp
g++ -O3 -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic   BenchmarkFunctors.o main.o Utils.o -o vectorbenchmark2
```

[Test suite code](http://www.mitalia.net/uploads/Matteo/vectorbenchmark2.tar.gz)

Comment: `sized with constructor/operator[]` (with no checks when iterating, no chance to go above if used just as is) is just around 5.4% faster than `(push_back/iterator, with reserve)` (which comes with all runtime checks, knows exact amount of items added, ...). It is not worth to go with more performant and much less convenient option in 99% of use cases as for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to avoid as many allocations as possible -- things are just faster that way. :)

By the way, the mere fact that vector allocates space dynamically doesn't really change anything -- it's the fact that it *doubles* its size (or otherwise changes it by a constant *factor*, rather than increase it by a constant value, that makes things more efficient. If you're interested, take a look at [complexity analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms).

---

*Edit:*

Example:

If you have 1000 elements and you have to add another element, you don't want to just make the array bigger by 1, because right after you add yet *another* element, you have to resize it again. But if you, say, double its size, it'll take *n* operations before you have to allocate and copy *n* items, so, per item, the cost is one. (See the link for more info.)

Comment: Can you give any illustrative example

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I made an edit. Does that help? :)

Comment: when you edit, can you put "EDIT :"   then write your opinion?

Comment: Sorry, sometimes I do that and sometimes I forget. I'll change it right now. :)

Answer (score 0):

By preallocating space for a vector we need to be sure that we will not exceed that much memory by pushing data into the vector.
If we insert more data than an available free block of memory (as vector alllocates in contiguous memory) then whatever data was pushed in vector up till now is copied and is allocated a new block of memory , which can degrade your performance and also if any iterator was pointing to your vector becomes invalid as for the data a new memory location has been allotted.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, but if you are referring to the optimisation of pre-reserving enough space in your `std::vector` when you know how many elements you'll need, then it's because `std::vector` will otherwise resize several times as you add elements one-by-one to it.

When you reserve space, you tell it that you know how much space it'll end up needing and it doesn't have to keep guessing. This avoids the repeated allocate-and-copy.

It's usually not important, but it's *definitely* a consideration when you have a very large vector and you know beforehand just how large it'll be: why would you not reserve enough space for it?